# Animation of an oscillating ball

Tags: plotting, animation

I need to represent the oscillation of a ball within a well. The well is represented by y=x^2 on [-1,1] and the position of the ball is x=Sin[t]. How can I overlay the animation on a static graph? Also what are the correct values of t and y to use?

This is what I have so far:

```
Animate[Graphics[Point[Table[{x^2, Sin[t]}, {t, -1.57, 1.57}]]], {x, -1, 1}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for based on the code shown. My interpretation of the text of your question would be something like this:

```
Animate[
  Plot[
    x^2,
    {x, -1, 1},
    Epilog -> {
      AbsolutePointSize[8],
      Point[{Sin[t], Sin[t]^2}]
    }
  ],
  {t, 0, 2 Pi}
]
```

[image: Animation of a ball in a potential well.]

If the position of the ball should be $x = \sin(t)$, then we can determine the y value from the equation for the potential. $y = x^2 = (x)^2 = (\sin(t))^2 = \sin^2(t)$.